# efficiently converting a bijection to cycle notation

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, permutation

Consider the following problem. Given is an array P of length n representing a bijection. That is element 0 <= i < n is mapped to P[i].

Given that P is a permutation, it can be written in cycle notation as described for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation).

For example if

```
P = [16, 3, 10, 6, 5, 9, 1, 19, 13, 14, 7, 0, 2, 8, 12, 4, 17, 15, 11, 18]
```

then the result in cycle notation would be

```
[(16, 17, 15, 4, 5, 9, 14, 12, 2, 10, 7, 19, 18, 11, 0), (3, 6, 1), (13, 8)]
```

Following is a Python method accomplishing this

```
def toCycle(p):
    covered = cur = 0 
    perm = []    
    n = len(p)
    done = [0]*n
    while covered < n:
        while cur < n and done[cur] == -1: 
            cur+=1
        cycle = [p[cur]]
        sec = p[p[cur]]
        done[p[cur]] = -1
        done[cur] = -1
        covered+=1
        while sec != cycle[0]:
            cycle.append(sec)
            done[sec] = -1
            sec = p[sec]
            covered+=1
        perm+=[tuple(cycle)]
    return perm
```

The algorithm clearly runs in linear time (each element of done/p is accessed a constant number of times) and hence there is not much that can be done asymptotically.

As I have to use this method on a large number of large permutations I was wondering

> Can you make it faster? Do you have any suggestions for performance
>   improvement?

Comment: Given that you must visit every entry in the list in order to transform the list, you can't do better than linear. However, as shown in the answer below, you can reduce the coefficient of the linear algorithm somewhat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cycling(p, start, done):
    while not done[e]:
        done[e] = True
        e = p[e]
        yield e

def toCycle(p):
    done = [False]*len(p)
    cycles = [tuple(cycling(p, 0, done))]
    while not all(done):
        start = done.index(False)
        cycles.append(tuple(cycling(p, start, done)))
    return cycles
```

With your example my code runs about 30% faster than yours.